# Touches a text filed clicks a Button behind it in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a serious of radio buttons and on clicking a particular button a text field will become visible above it and on clicking other buttons text view will become hidden. When I touches the textfield to enter text on the textfield the button behind it will get clicked and textfiled got hidden. I can only able to type in the text filed if I click on the area of the text field thats not overlapping with the buttons. How can make the button behind the textfield not cickable when I touches the textfield.

Comment: please post code you have used to bring textField on top of your radio button, also radio button isnt a native button it must be your custom implementation post the code for that as well to help us understand your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help sandeep. Actually I have added the textfield inside the view which radio buttons. After adding the textfield outside that view tise issue got solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish your textfield make front of button view then you should make it frount of it show please do as below

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: textField)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rakesh. Actually I have added the textfield inside the view which radio buttons. After adding the textfield outside that view tise issue got solved.